# Gitlab - Couldn't push to Repository just hangs

Tags: git, gitlab

Couldn't push to master, console just freezes without any response. Only after running

`git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

`git push` works just fine.

Although the setting seems to be onetime, the next time when using `git push` ending up with the same issue.
Is there an alternative solution? And why this happens all of a sudden?

Edit:

`OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/name/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:5bed:a9b9] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/name/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.9`

Comment: How reliable is your Internet connection?  Are you using HTTPS or SSH?  Do you have an antivirus, firewall, or MITM proxy on your computer or network?  If so, does using a different network or completely uninstalling the software make it work?

Comment: @bk2204 Internet is reliable. I'm using SSH. Firewall and other I guess is not a problem as I can push changes soon after running `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

Comment: That option has no effect on SSH at all.  What you're seeing is likely a network problem of some sort, so the firewall is definitely relevant.  Try running `ssh -vvv git@gitlab.com` and editing your question to include the relevant  output.

Comment: @bk2204 added the result as an edit.

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is a network problem of some sort.  You're able to connect to the remote system, but you're unable to read the remote side's version string, which is the first thing it sends as part of the SSH protocol.

It is likely that there is something on your system that's preventing the data from being sent or received, or that there's something on your network that's causing this.  It looks like you're on macOS by your OpenSSH version string, so you should check the firewall configuration.  If you have installed an antivirus on your system, remove it and then restart.  Some networks block SSH, so that could also be the problem.  If trying an `ssh git@github.com` does not hang, then this could be because your network has broken IPv6 support or broken Path MTU discovery, in which case you should check your router.  You can try from another network (if that's possible given current events) and see if that fixes the problem, in which case you know it's something on your network.

There are so many potential problems here that it's impossible to enumerate them all.  What definitely will not help is changing `http.postBuffer`, since that has no effect on SSH at all and only affects HTTPS connections where the server or a proxy has broken HTTP/1.1 support.  It should not be set unless you know you need it, because it causes every HTTPS push operation, no matter how small, to allocate that full amount of memory, so in almost every situation, it provides no benefit and just wastes tons of memory needlessly.

You could also try switching to an HTTPS URL instead.  Sometimes that works better for some reason.

Comment: Much appreciated thank you. Will try out your suggestions.